# Deploying DAG to airflow running on kubernetes (via helm)

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm

What's the easiest/best way to get the code of my DAG onto an instance of airflow that's running on kubernetes (setup via helm)?

I see in the `airflow-airflow-config` ConfigMap that `dags_folder = /opt/airflow/dags` is defined.
But unlike in the local environment, it doesn't pick up the DAGs I add to the folder (via `kubectl cp`).

Also, in a production environment I obviously don't want to rely on manual syncing of scripts. I assume they DAGs should be stored in some kind of DB or persistent volume(?)

Answer (score 0):

There are different options to deploy DAGs to airflow when using the helm kubernetes deployment, for example deploying them as container images or using a Git-Sync sidecar.
See full documentation here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/manage-dags-files.html